# Fix the noise this damper is making

Tags: hvac, ducts

I recently moved to a new house and the damper in the HVAC air duct is making this very loud noise. I think it is loose and flapping around as air passes through it. I tried to tape the handle, but that did not fix the problem. The handle is not moving that much, i think it is the rod? I am not sure how I can fix this. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Here is a [video](https://imgur.com/a/IGk0PAQ).

Comment: Please revise your post to describe the noise and add information about the damper, such as its location and purpose. Questions should not be dependent on content at other websites. Take the [tour] for tips.